# Filtering SQL queries

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I'm creating a php query trying to filter from a specific SQL table specific Events.
For example table is called **tbl_events** and one specific column is showing user ID data let's call it **USER_ID**
The table has more than 50.000 data lines so if I try and filter it with php it takes TOO much time. So my try is to filter it with SQL before I show the query to the php table and see if it becomes faster.

I want to filter the query in order **NOT to show** the ones who have an ID let's say "2"
My code is the following (and its obviously not working)

```
$GetEventsList = GetDataWhere("tbl_events","USER_ID!=2",0);
```

I'm new in SQL commands so be patient :)

Comment: You'd have to show the content of that `GetDataWhere` function for more accurate answers; but the way you're currently doing it is a bad idea. If it doesn't work at all that is likely because your database doesn't understand the `!=` operator. Most dbms use `<>` instead, however writing the data (in this case the number `2`, directly into the SQL string is a very bad idea (think `SQL injection`). The right way to do it however depends entirely on what that `GetDataWhere` function contains.

Comment: Not working how? What error do you get? What does the `GetDataWhere` look like? have you tried `USER_ID <> 2`?

Comment: Is your table have index on field USER_ID?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

**Query**:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE USER_ID != '2'
```

So to implement this with php I would *suggest*:

```
$servername = "Your server ip here";
$username = "Database_username_here";
$password = "Database_password_here";
$dbname = "Database_name_here";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE USER_ID != '2'";

// Run $sql content as sql script in db.
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```